# Word Hunt: Audio Player Terminology

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, music

I'm looking for a few words today, in the context of Audio Players. I'm basically looking for words that match the following definitions:

Here are my current known words, and their definitions:

- **Player** - The Audio Player itself.
- **Buffer** - The Audio that has been loaded/stream already for the User
- **Play Button** - The Button that Plays, Pauses, and Resumes the Audio.
- **Volume** - The amplitude of the Audio.

And here's my definitions that need words:

- **Needle?** - The Marker that represents the current position *(time)* in the Song.
  [image: Needle]
- **Time?** - A term meaning "The current position *(time)* in the song".
  [image: Time]
- **Track?** - A term meaning the entire time, buffer, needle, etc. mashed up into a widget.
  [image: Track]

The words I've provided are mere suggestions. I'm here asking about these because they just don't seem right. **Needle** could be **Marker**, **Indicator**, **Position**, **Slider**, etc.; **Time** could be **Position**, **Length**, etc.; and **Track** could **Slider**, **Widget**, etc.

I would prefer terms that are used when talking about Music, or Audio Devices. Generic terms like **Time** could have many meanings. And **Needle** doesn't really describe the object in question, as it's not really a 'needle' *(Metallic, pointy object)*.

Comment: Song position drag handle. Song elapsed time. Song position indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Marker that represents the current position (time) in the Song.

[image]

**Answer**:

> ***Seek Bar Thumb (more of a programming term)*** or ***Slider Handle***

2. A term meaning "The current position (time) in the song".

[image]

**Answer**:

> ***Current Time*** or ***Elapsed Track time***

3. A term meaning the entire time, buffer, needle, etc. mashed up into a widget.

[image]

**Answer**:

> ***Seek Bar***

---

Note: I have no references to this answer. I once worked on a requirement to design a sticky media player widget and I know these terms thanks to the wire-frames provided by UX team. Just search with the aforementioned terms in StackOverflow. You'll find numerous pertinent questions and usage examples.

For instance, see questions related to [seek bar](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=seek+bar) or [seek bar thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=seek+bar+thumb).

**Update**:

As @[Chris H](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/48571/chris-h) notes, *seek bar thumb* seems to be more of a programming term. I have updated answer accordingly.

Comment: *seek bar thumb* is probably a programmers' term rather than one for users - certainly I've never come across it (including when writing desktop software). *Slider* seems more common, but that can refer to the whole *seek bar* as well. The bit you drag could be the *slider **handle***. *Seek bar* is pretty self-explanatory to a native speaker but *seek bar thumb* isn't.

Comment: @ChrisH - Point Noted. Answer updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Two thirds of your question is about the names of the components of a scroll bar control:

> [image]
>
> [devx.com](http://www.devx.com/DevX/Article/42947/0/page/5)

As for time, yes we call it time.